# SharedPreferences doesn't work in FirebaseMessageService when app is closed

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I've tried everything to get `PreferenceManagers` default `SharedPreferences` into my `FirebaseMessageService.onMessageReceived` when the app is closed, but I just can't get it to work. I can't seem to find out why this isn't possible.

I want the user to be able to turn off notifications from my settings panel, where there's a switch for *Receive notifications*.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("receive_notifications", true) == true) {
   notificationManager.notify(0, notifiBuilder.build());
}
```

It will use the default value of true, no matter what the setting is.

Everything works perfect if the user is in the app, but not when it's closed.

Answer (score 0):

Use getApplicationContext() instead this.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext())
```